# How to get value inside closure php

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get a variable inside a closure of `each` function that I defined above it. but it returns null:

```
public function saveSettingsImages(Collection $collection) : array
{
    $arrImages = Array();
    $collection->each(function (UploadedFile $file) use ($arrImages) {
        $filename = $file->store('sliders', ['disk' => 'public']);
        echo $filename; // it prints name of file as well
        array_push($arrImages,$filename);
    });
    dd($arrImages);//it is empty array
    return $arrImages;
}
```

but `dd($arrImages);` is empty!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing the reference to the variable instead like

```
$collection->each(function (UploadedFile $file) use (&$arrImages) {
    $filename = $file->store('sliders', ['disk' => 'public']);
    echo $filename; // it prints name of file as well
    array_push($arrImages,$filename);
});
```